# JavaScript works in IE, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, .net, firefox, visibility

In my .NET project I'm using a Button in HTML page that brings a hidden `<div>`. That `<div>` contains a form to insert a company.

HTML:

```
<div class="top-div-where-is-my-ADD-button">
    <h2>
        Search:
        <input type="text" id="search" />
        <div id="divADD" onclick="AddCompany()">
            <span>Add Company</span></div>
    </h2>
</div>

    <div id="hide" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <table id="CompanyDetails" class="company" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
.........
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function AddCompany() {
    HideCompany();
    $(hide).css({ visibility: "visible", height: "auto" });
    var a = document.getElementById("divbuttonSaveCompany");
    a.onclick = InsertCompany; 
}

function InsertCompany() {
    var a = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("Address").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("Country").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("Phone").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("Fax").value;
    var f = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    var gg = document.getElementById("Contact");
    var g = gg.options[gg.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddCompany", "Company")',
        data: { nameCompany: a, address: b, country: c, phone: d, fax: e, email: f , contact: g},
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Company was successfully added! ");
            $("#all").html(data);
        }
    });
}
function HideCompany() {
    $(hide).css({ visibility: "hidden", height: "0" });
    $("#Name").val("");
    $("#Address").val("");
    $("#Country").val("");
    $("#Phone").val("");
    $("#Fax").val("");
    $("#Email").val("");
}
```

So basically in IE when I push the button AddCompany the hidden `<div>` appears, but in FF doesn't.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Any errors in the FF console?

Comment: I guess you didn't see the big "DO NOT USE" hint on the [tag:hidden] tag.

Comment: in FF console i have this: ascunde is not defined
HideCompany()Institution (line 167)
AddCompany()Institution (line 134)
onclick()onclick (line 2)
event = click clientX=1172, clientY=187
[Break On This Error]  

$(hide).css({ visibility: "hidden", height: "0" });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
$(hide)
```

That works in IE because IE makes a global variable from every element with an "id".  Firefox won't do that.

Change all references to `$(hide)` to `$('#hide')`.

Comment: Well, this is interesting. I had just supposed it was defined elsewhere but you're probably right. Some MS guys had really strange ideas...

Answer (score 1):

Use [the jQuery `hide` function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide an element, and [the `show` function](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to display it.

Setting the height to 0 is non-standard.

Comment: That's not the correct way to hide. Depending on the other elements, it could have side effects. And it doesn't even always work. If you want to hide, hide.

Comment: Well I don't think that's the problem here anyway.

Comment: I agree. The difference here is not JavaScript, it is CSS. jQuery is good at fixing some irregularities between browser platforms, so leverage it for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the *display* property instead of *visibility*?

When using *visibility* th eelement takes up space even if not displayed, using *display* the element take sup no space, so you don't need worrying about the *height*.

Also you seem to be using jQuery, could you toogle the visibility of your div using

> $(hide).show();
>
> $(hide).hide();

or simply

> $(hide).toggle();

These are jQuery shortcuts that use the css *display* property [(see doc)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks Pointy